# Resample 'ohlc' aggregate fails when there are list of functions in dictionary for multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, aggregation

I'm trying to downsample using pandas resample / agg functionalities.
I have to apply different functions to each of multiple columns of dataframe.

I found agg process complains error message, when native 'ohlc' function come with 'list of function' for other columns in function dictionary

The below is simplified code for testing.

```
date = pd.date_range('2019-10-01', periods=9, freq='D')  
tick = {'price':[1000, 1050, 1050, 1100, 1150, 1100, 1000, 950, 950],  
    'buy':[20, 50, 1000, 2000, -500, -10, -3500, -5000, 5]}  

df = pd.DataFrame(tick, index=date)  
functions = {'price':'ohlc', 'buy':['mean', 'sum']}  

ds = df.resample('3D').agg(functions)
```

My real code has 5 columns and each of which has to be applied some function during resampling. and It has been no error with ONE function per each column.

I found other solution of using function list like

```
functions = {'price':[("open", "first"), ("high", "max"), ("low", "min"), ("close", "last")], 'buy':['mean', 'sum']
```

But I'd like to know what is wrong with my code.

And error message contains

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'dict'>"; only 
pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

Comment: What is 'ohlc' function, and where is it defined?

Comment: ohlc is method of pandas resampler, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/resampling.html